# Multiple MongoDB database triggers in same Python module

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to implement multiple database triggers for my MongoDB (connected through Pymongo to my Python code).

I am able to successfully implement *a* database trigger but not able to extend this to multiple ones.

The code for the single database trigger can be found below:

```
try:
    resume_token = None
    pipeline = [{"$match": {"operationType": "insert"}}]
    with db.collection.watch(pipeline) as stream:
        for insert_change in stream:
            print("postprocessing logic goes here")
except pymongo.errors.PyMongoError:
    logging.error("Oops")
```

The problem is that once a single database is implemented, the post processing code waits to receive incoming requests for that collection and am able to include other collection watches in the same module.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Create separate functions for each watch and launch them in [separate threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) with something like:

```
import queue
import threading

main_q = queue.Queue()
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=function1, args=(main_q, None))
thread1.daemon = True
thread1.start()

thread2 = threading.Thread(target=function2, args=(main_q,))
thread2.daemon = True
thread2.start()
```